# Joomla login simple script

Tags: authentication, joomla

I created a simple login form that posts data to _self and then I tried to check the credentials in order to log the user in.

The authenticating script looks like that:

```
if ($_POST['username'] && $_POST['password'] )

{
      $db =& JFactory::getDBO();

      $query = 'SELECT `id`'
            . ' FROM #__users'
            . ' WHERE username='.$_POST['username'];
      $db->setQuery( $query );
      $result = $db->loadResult();


        if (!$result) {
            echo 'User does not exist';
        }


        if($result && (USERNAME & PASS MATCH))
        {
           << LOGIN AND REDIRECT TO CERTAIN PAGE >>
        }
        else
        {
            echo 'Invalid username or password';
        }   


}
```

In my simple php scripts, I used to set a SESSION variable to true when username and password match and thats how I considered a user to be logged in.

Here, what actions should I do? Is there a field in the database that is set when user is logged in? In other words, I want to log the user in and then redirect to another page.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Joomla! has a complete user management system, so I'm not clear from your question what your purpose is. Are you trying to create an extension for Joomla! or something else?

Answer (score 1):

Once the user is logged in, you could do something like:

```
    if($result && (USERNAME & PASS MATCH))
    {
       $_SESSION['logged_in_user'] = $user;
       header("location: /loggedin.php");
    }
```

Then at the top of `loggedin.php` set an authentication check:

```
session_start(); // If 
if (!isset($_SESSION['logged_in_user'])) {
    // User is not logged in, so send user away.
    header("Location:/login");
    die();
}
// User is logged in; private code goes here.
```

This is a great tutorial for user login systems: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/PHP_Programming/User_login_systems

It goes into advanced user authentication and shows more examples than I have here.

Comment: Thanks a lot Patrick, but like I said, I am used to this kind of writing. However, I am afraid that joomla does not work that way! I think I am not supposed to use session variables. That is why I am confused.. Any other suggestion?

Comment: The only other thing you could do besides sessions would be a database-based authentication system, e.g. mysql, or even something like memcached, but sessions do a good job of authentication if done correctly. Other than that, you don't really need too much complexity for simple user authentication.